# JavaFX Observable Beans Generator?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, observable

Are there are any plugins out there for Eclipse that can generate a POJO using an observable pattern?

It seems like it would be really easy to do, but I don't have the time to learn FastCode or Xpand/MWE2.

This is all that needs to be done. Take any particular observable property:

```
StringProperty myThing = new SimpleStringProperty();
```

and generate its getters, setters, and property getter.

```
public void setMyThing(String input){ myThing.set(input); }
public String getMyThing(){ return myThing.get(); }
public StringProperty myThingProperty(){ return myThing; }
```

Of course, this also applies to SimpleObjectProperty< T > items.

Comment: Idea does this, but it's not Eclipse.  Does [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) provide this?  If not, file a feature request against the e(fx)clipse project requesting the feature. Also see the [property cookbook](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/JavaFX+Property+Architecture).

Answer (score 1):

In Intellij Idea when you tip alt + inser, select generate getter and setter, select your property and it's done